# Неверный синтаксис while - as

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой вот код:

```
 while Listener(on_p=on_p) as listener:
        listenet.join()
```

При попытке запуска выдает ошибку:
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, указывает на `as`...
Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка?
PS Использую версию пайтона 3.7

Comment: Конструкции while-as никогда не существовало в питоне

Comment: Собственно, а что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: я только начал знакомиться с данным языком, читаю вот эту статью, пытаюсь понять https://pycoder.ru/python-with-statement/

Comment: @user007 по вашей ссылке тоже нет никакого while-as, зато есть with-as

Comment: @user007 знакомство с языком надо начинать с учебника, а не статей.

Answer (score 0):

Не такой конструкции. А вы имели в виду:

```
with Listener(on_p=on_p) as listener:
    listenet.join()
```